# jQuery template language: How to loop int in a list

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Suppose in a Java controller there is an endpoint which will return a JSON string containing:

```
sizeList: [1,2,3,4]
```

In the frontend JSP, if I use jQuery template language to loop through it, like this:

```
{{each sizeList}}
{{/each}}
```

How can I display the `1,2,3,4` output in the JSP?

Comment: Can you add what you've tried so far ?

Comment: I made: 
{{each sizeList}} {{= value}}  {{/each}}, 
{{each(value) sizeList}} {{= value}}  {{/each}},
{{each(value) sizeList}} ${{value}}  {{/each}},
{{each(value) sizeList}} ${value}  {{/each}},

But none of above work, I now suppose Jquery teamplate language not support auto un-box @Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

OK, I self confirm it. The Jquery template do not support auto un-box. Not support in controller has List, it must has List, and each Item has value properties to contain an Integer